# How to cancel long running ADF pipelines using the logic app

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-data-factory, azure-logic-apps

I have a logic app query to get the details of long running pipelines and I sending the email with the pipeline names. Now I want to cancel those pipelines which are running for long time how Can I implement with Logic app ?

Comment: Have you tried anything in specific? And what is "long time" in your requirement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the intend is to cancel a long running ADF pipeline , you can do that from ADF only ( using a different pipeline)

- using web activity. [Get the running pipeline](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/datafactory/pipeline-runs/get?tabs=HTTP#pipelinerun) ( Saideep has mentioned this in his response )
- Use the durationInMs property to get "for how long is this running "
- Use the runid to cancel the run : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/datafactory/pipeline-runs/cancel?tabs=HTTP

Comment: Hi Himanshu, I am trying to implement in ADF by using the lookup activity(I am writing a query to get the pipelines details to be cancelled) I am getting details of pipeline to be cancelled  May I know which activity to be used to cancel those pipelines ?

Comment: Now I am using ADF pipeline to cancel the pipelines with the help of lookup activity I am getting RUNID of the pipeline to be canceled.. May I know which activity we can use to cancel the pipeline by passing RUNID from lookup activity ?

Answer (score 1):

- There is an action available directly in logic apps "Azure data factory" connector. The following is an example where you can cancel a pipeline run.
- The following is the flow of the logic app that I am using:

[image]

- The pipeline run is cancelled as shown in the below image:

[image]

- And a mail will be triggered as shown in the below image:

[image]

- If you want to get the pipeline runs dynamically, you can use the rest API specified in this [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/datafactory/pipeline-runs/get?tabs=HTTP#pipelinerun).
- You can loop through this list and check for whose status is "InProgress" and get the current running time to check if its long enough to cancel.

Comment: Hi Saideep, Now I am using ADF pipeline to cancel the pipelines with the help of lookup activity I am getting RUNID of the pipeline to be canceled.. May I know which activity we can use to cancel the pipeline by passing RUNID from lookup activity